# what are the efficient ways to migrate data from mariadb to oracle database

Tags: database, oracle, mariadb, database-migration

I have a requirement to migrate one of our prod database from mariadb to oracle database.I searched for ways to migrate the data.But need some suggestions or standard procedures for migration.Need help!!

Comment: If you can get the Mariadb into Excel (e.g. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-for-excel/en/mysql-for-excel-export.html), then you can use SQL Developer (free, no cost from Oracle with an otn account).  Jeff Smith documented, https://www.thatjeffsmith.com/archive/2012/04/how-to-import-from-excel-to-oracle-with-sql-developer/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to use 3rd party application such as SQL developer or DBSOFT

Comment: are those softwares open source?

Comment: Yes , 
SQL Developer by Oracle
https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-v192-downloads.html

DBSOFT
https://www.dbsofts.com/articles/mariadb_to_oracle/

Comment: I can see the trial version of DBSOFT esftoolkit.Is there any limitations in a trial version?

Comment: the limitation related to data size but the software itself is cheap, you can also use SQL developer and configure it and install mariaDB plugin and migrate to Oracle very simple

Answer (score 1):

You can use tool like **pentaho Spoon**. 
It has support to move data from one DB to other.